# Can a pam module modify the password typed by the user before it is seen by other modules?

Tags: pam, error-correction, ecryptfs, password-generator

**Background:** I have written a password generator that works as follows:

- Generate 130 random bits
- Interpret random bits as 26 elements of `GF(32)`
- Use the elements as coefficients to construct a 25th degree polynomium
- Evaluate the polynomium for all 32 possible inputs
- Encode the result using a modified base32 encoding

This gives me strong passwords (130 bits of entropy) where a few typos while entering the password can be tolerated without compromising security.

So far I have integrated the error correction part of the algorithm with the `ssh-add` command, this is working flawless. Now I'd like the same smooth usage for my login password.

**Question:** Is it possible to write a `pam` module, which changes the password as entered by the user before it is seen by other modules? In particular I would like to ensure that `ecryptfs` see the corrected password, such that the home directory can be mounted after my algorithm has corrected a typo in the password entered by the user?

Answer (score 0):

There is no obvious way to do this as a separate module. But it can be done with a simple modification to the `pam_unix` module.

Towards the end of `pam_sm_authenticate()` in `modules/pam_unix/pam_unix_auth.c` the following code is found:

```
    /* verify the password of this user */
    retval = _unix_verify_password(pamh, name, p, ctrl);
    name = p = NULL;
```

This can be modified to apply the error correction I need:

```
    /* verify the password of this user */
    retval = _unix_verify_password(pamh, name, p, ctrl);
    if (retval == PAM_AUTH_ERR) {
        apply_error_correction(p);
        retval = _unix_verify_password(pamh, name, p, ctrl);
    }
    name = p = NULL;
```